# Nonparametric hypothesis test for ratio of medians

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, bootstrap, median

I have 4 distributions:
A1, A2, B1, and B2.

I would like to test whether there is a significant difference between median(A1)/median(A2) and median(B1)/median(B2). While I can calculate propagated errors for these ratios from the original four distributions, I'm not exactly sure how to run anything other than a t-test for this comparison since I only have one number for each ratio rather than a full distribution. Is there a way to run a nonparametric test with just the individual ratio values and a propagated error? Or is there some kind of bootstrapping that might make sense for determining whether there is a difference between the ratios of medians?

Comment: Do you have *distributions* or do you have *samples?*  Comparing ratios will be particularly challenging if there's any appreciable probability of either denominator being $0.$

Comment: Samples. 0 is not included in the 99% confidence interval of any of the four

Comment: Are all four samples independent?

Comment: No, each one is a different metric that comes from the same group of subjects.

Comment: That is a critically important fact: please edit your post to include a fuller description of your data.